# Adopting Wavemaker on Cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

As regards cloudfoundry platform

- is there the possibility to implement a multi-tenant solution? The customer should be able to manage multi-tenancy from a dashboard or “provider console”
- is there the possibility to grant permissions and create access roles on a per-user basis?
- is there a control panel where the admin user will have direct access to main services (mysql, mongodb,redis, dea, etc)?

As regards application/web development

- Is the code versioning (cvs, svn) implemented as module of cloudfoundry or delivered in the vfabric suite?
- Is there the possibility to adopt a workflow to track all the phases of application development (design, development, integration and test, implementation, operation)?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here are your answers:

- Cloud Foundry platform is a multi-tenant solution in that it allows for multiple users and each user's applications are shielded from others.
- There are two types of roles for Cloud Foundry today:admin and user.
- There isn't a UI web application tool as of today. You can access your apps deployed to cloud foundry by using the vmc CLI tool. Accessing services is possible using vmc tunnel. See http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/tools/vmc/caldecott.html

As regarding to web development:

- No. However one can look at those as a service...
- Workflow is usually tool or process based. There is no offer of an application development tracking tool in Cloud Foundry today.